# Lomuto Quicksort takes less comparions to sort a backwards list than a pre-sorted list

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

This quicksort is taking a different number of comparisons to sort a pre-sorted list compared to the same list pre-sorted in the opposite direction. Help appreciated!

I have heard from my fellow students that this should not be the case. Apparently both directions should take the same number of comparisons.

Quick Sort Method:

```
public static void QS (String[] a){

    QS_Recurse(a,0,(a.length-1));

}

private static void QS_Recurse(String[] sorting, int beginning, int end){

if (end > beginning){

    String pivot_switcher;

    String string_switcher;

    String pivot = sorting[beginning];

    int middle = beginning;

    for (int r = beginning + 1; r <= end; r++){

        if (sorting[r].compareTo(pivot) <= 0){

            string_switcher = sorting[middle+1];

            sorting[middle+1] = sorting[r];

            sorting[r] = string_switcher;

            middle++;

            }

        comparisons++;

        }

    pivot_switcher = sorting[middle];

    sorting[middle] = pivot;

    sorting[beginning] = pivot_switcher;

    QS_Recurse(sorting,beginning,middle-1);

    QS_Recurse(sorting,middle+1,end);       

    }   

}
```

Comment: The crucial point in quicksort is to choose a good pivot point.  You may want to print out the values of "beginning" and "end" when running your program and see if they correspond to your expectations from running the algorithm by hand.

Comment: My teacher insisted that all of our sorts choose the first item to be the pivot. I'm confused as to how my code could be performing "better" than expected like this

Comment: New information - The error is only happening when the inputted list is 1000. I changed the variable maxsize and that didnt help

Comment: Already-sorted data is a worst case for Quicksort unless the pivot point is carefully chosen.

Comment: I know, but shouldnt it be the same if the data is sorted forwards or backwards? I am getting different #'s of comparisons when a 1000 word list is sorted, when it is pre-sorted forwards or backwards

Comment: I think you should create a small example (10-20 items in the list) and run the algorithm completely by hand, including the recursive calls!  Then check if your code does what you expect it to.  This will most likely also clarify why a previously sorted list is a worst case.

Comment: The reason why sorted is the worst case is that it produces partitions of size 1. Reverse-sorted doesn't have that effect.